# Quiz app using titanium and sqlite not giving me the result

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, titanium

Hi I am making a quiz app using titanium.I have shown the answers using label.My code is as follows

```
    var options = db.execute('select * from Answers');

var laboption1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : options.fieldByName('Answer'),
top : '10%',
left : '10%',
color:'black'
 });
 QuizWin.add(laboption1);
 var laboption2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : options.fieldByName('Answer'),
top : '15%',
left : '10%',
color:'black'
 });
 QuizWin.add(laboption2);
 var laboption3 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : options.fieldByName('Answer'),
top : '20%',
left : '10%',
color:'black'
});
QuizWin.add(laboption3);
var laboption4 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : options.fieldByName('Answer'),
top : '25%',
left : '10%',
color:'black'

});
QuizWin.add(laboption4);
```

The result of my sql query is as follows

```
   Lahore
   Karachi
    Quetta
   Peshawar
```

But it is showing only lahore(First Entry) in each entry.Plz help me in this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprinkle these checking for valid rows and moving to the next record between all but the first label creation.

```
options.isValidRow() // Check that there is another row in the set

options.next(); // move to the next row in the set of data
```